# SSRS: How can I accessing report parameters from custom assembly?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Is there any way to access report parameters from within a custom assembly? I can pass them explicitly as part of function calls, but that can be quite cumbersome for very complex reports.

Thanks,

Adrian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can. The [corresponding MSDN documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159238.aspx#Parameters) mentions that you *can* use parameters in custom assemblies:

> You can reference the global parameters collection via custom code in a Code block of the report definition or in a custom assembly that you provide. The parameters collection is read-only and has no public iterators.

But the examples provided both require you to provide all parameters or just one as an argument to the custom code functions, e.g.

```vb
' Passing an entire global parameter collection to custom code.
' This function returns the value of a specific report parameter MyParameter.
Public Function DisplayAParameterValue(ByVal parameters as Parameters) as Object
    Return parameters("MyParameter").Value
End Function
```

And:

```vb
' Passing an individual parameter to custom code.
' This example returns the value of the parameter
' passed in. If the parameter is a multivalue parameter, 
' the return string is a concatenation of all the values.
Public Function ShowParameterValues(ByVal parameter as Parameter)
 as String
   Dim s as String 
   If parameter.IsMultiValue then
      s = "Multivalue: " 
      For i as integer = 0 to parameter.Count-1
         s = s + CStr(parameter.Value(i)) + " " 
      Next
   Else
      s = "Single value: " + CStr(parameter.Value)
   End If
   Return s
End Function
```